# Add a string to a input from form

Tags: javascript, string, input

So, I am a real beginner in js and I have a form with 2 inputs. In this inputs I have date pickers so that the user can select a date from a calendar. But the db from the site I work on has this date format: Y M D 0000:00:00. I want to add those zeros at the end automatically when a user  selects a date. Don't know if anyone can help, but thanks.

```
window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d"
        });
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField2",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%M-%d"
        });
    };
<form action="insert.php" method="post" target="000:00:00 "onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<label for="FUP start date">FUP start date:</label> 
<input type="text" name="inputField" id="inputField"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="FUP end date">FUP end date:&nbsp;</label> 
<input type="text" name="inputField2" id="inputField2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you can simply alter the `dateFormat` given to each `JsDatePick` to include those zeroes, like so:

```
new JsDatePick({
  useMode: 2,
  target: "inputField",
  dateFormat: "%Y-%M-%d 0000:00:00"
});
```

It would be helpful if you could provide information on the date picker you are using.

Comment: yes, thanks. that was easy. I assumed I have to do something more difficult.